# Javascript variable in place of string fails request to Parse.com server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

I expect this will be very simple for someone. I am trying to pass some key value pairs as a query to Parse.com javascript API. The documented format is as follows and works fine:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("testUser");
    query.containedIn("facebookID",["10101185732529914", "10101185732529915"]);
    query.find()
    .then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });
```

However I want to pull the IDs from an array and pass them in so I have used the following code to do so (the x variable being the array):

```
var text = '';
    for (index = 0; index < x.length; index++) {
        text += '"' + x[index]['$id'] + '"';
    }
    text += '';
    var requestString = text.replace(/""/g, '", "');
```

If I `console.log(requestString);`this shows the data in the format I need, e.g. "10101185732529914", "10101185732529915"

As such the updated request code with the variable instead of the text is now:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("testUser");
    query.containedIn("facebookID",[requestString]);
    query.find()
    .then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });
```

This however does not work, I am assuming this is due to the format of the variable. The relevant section of Parse.com API docs is here...https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries-query-constraints

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Ant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted the problem, it wanted an array not a string, as such...

```
var text=[];
    for (index = 0; index < x.length; index++) {

        text.push(x[index]['$id']);
    }
    var requestString = text;
```

and

```
var query = new Parse.Query("testUser");
    query.containedIn("facebookID",requestString);
    query.find()
    .then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Thanks

Ant